# Using PHP array to populate a price field based on date ranges and types

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays, date

I'm trying to use a PHP array to populate a price field in a form I'm building for customers to order lift tickets.  I have the array listed below.  What I am trying to accomplish is that when a customer picks a date from a datepicker in the form, the type of ticket, and number of tickets, then the price would populate (or echo) into a div.  Below is the array:

```
$rackrates2016 = array(
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 1','early' => '$10 ','middec' => '$10 ','christmas' => '$10 ','powder' => '$10 ','presidents' => '$10 ','spring' => '$10 ','springbreak' => '$10 ','late' => '$10 ','closing' => '$10 '),
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 2','early' => '$20 ','middec' => '$20 ','christmas' => '$20 ','powder' => '$20 ','presidents' => '$20 ','spring' => '$20 ','springbreak' => '$20 ','late' => '$20 ','closing' => '$20 '),
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 3','early' => '$30 ','middec' => '$30 ','christmas' => '$30 ','powder' => '$30 ','presidents' => '$30 ','spring' => '$30 ','springbreak' => '$30 ','late' => '$30 ','closing' => '$30 '),
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 4','early' => '$30 ','middec' => '$30 ','christmas' => '$30 ','powder' => '$30 ','presidents' => '$30 ','spring' => '$30 ','springbreak' => '$30 ','late' => '$30 ','closing' => '$30 '),
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 5','early' => '$30 ','middec' => '$30 ','christmas' => '$30 ','powder' => '$30 ','presidents' => '$30 ','spring' => '$30 ','springbreak' => '$30 ','late' => '$30 ','closing' => '$30 '),
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 6','early' => '$30 ','middec' => '$30 ','christmas' => '$30 ','powder' => '$30 ','presidents' => '$30 ','spring' => '$30 ','springbreak' => '$30 ','late' => '$30 ','closing' => '$30 '),
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 7','early' => '$30 ','middec' => '$30 ','christmas' => '$30 ','powder' => '$30 ','presidents' => '$30 ','spring' => '$30 ','springbreak' => '$30 ','late' => '$30 ','closing' => '$30 '),
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 8','early' => '$30 ','middec' => '$30 ','christmas' => '$30 ','powder' => '$30 ','presidents' => '$30 ','spring' => '$30 ','springbreak' => '$30 ','late' => '$30 ','closing' => '$30 '),
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 9','early' => '$30 ','middec' => '$30 ','christmas' => '$30 ','powder' => '$30 ','presidents' => '$30 ','spring' => '$30 ','springbreak' => '$30 ','late' => '$30 ','closing' => '$30 '),
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 10','early' => '$30 ','middec' => '$30 ','christmas' => '$30 ','powder' => '$30 ','presidents' => '$30 ','spring' => '$30 ','springbreak' => '$30 ','late' => '$30 ','closing' => '$30 '),
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 11','early' => '$30 ','middec' => '$30 ','christmas' => '$30 ','powder' => '$30 ','presidents' => '$30 ','spring' => '$30 ','springbreak' => '$30 ','late' => '$30 ','closing' => '$30 '),
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 12','early' => '$30 ','middec' => '$30 ','christmas' => '$30 ','powder' => '$30 ','presidents' => '$30 ','spring' => '$30 ','springbreak' => '$30 ','late' => '$30 ','closing' => '$30 '),
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 13','early' => '$30 ','middec' => '$30 ','christmas' => '$30 ','powder' => '$30 ','presidents' => '$30 ','spring' => '$30 ','springbreak' => '$30 ','late' => '$30 ','closing' => '$30 '),
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 14','early' => '$30 ','middec' => '$30 ','christmas' => '$30 ','powder' => '$30 ','presidents' => '$30 ','spring' => '$30 ','springbreak' => '$30 ','late' => '$30 ','closing' => '$30 '),
  array('tickettype' => '5 and Under 15','early' => '$30 ','middec' => '$30 ','christmas' => '$30 ','powder' => '$30 ','presidents' => '$30 ','spring' => '$30 ','springbreak' => '$30 ','late' => '$30 ','closing' => '$30 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 1','early' => '$90.00','middec' => '$115.00 ','christmas' => '$130.00 ','powder' => '$115.00 ','presidents' => '$130.00 ','spring' => '$115.00 ','springbreak' => '$130.00 ','late' => '$115.00 ','closing' => '$90.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 2','early' => '$180.00 ','middec' => '$230.00 ','christmas' => '$260.00 ','powder' => '$230.00 ','presidents' => '$260.00 ','spring' => '$230.00 ','springbreak' => '$260.00 ','late' => '$230.00 ','closing' => '$180.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 3','early' => '$270.00 ','middec' => '$345.00 ','christmas' => '$390.00 ','powder' => '$345.00 ','presidents' => '$390.00 ','spring' => '$345.00 ','springbreak' => '$390.00 ','late' => '$345.00 ','closing' => '$270.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 4','early' => '$360.00 ','middec' => '$460.00 ','christmas' => '$520.00 ','powder' => '$460.00 ','presidents' => '$520.00 ','spring' => '$460.00 ','springbreak' => '$520.00 ','late' => '$460.00 ','closing' => '$360.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 5','early' => '$450.00 ','middec' => '$575.00 ','christmas' => '$650.00 ','powder' => '$575.00 ','presidents' => '$650.00 ','spring' => '$575.00 ','springbreak' => '$650.00 ','late' => '$575.00 ','closing' => '$450.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 6','early' => '$474.00 ','middec' => '$672.00 ','christmas' => '$762.00 ','powder' => '$672.00 ','presidents' => '$762.00 ','spring' => '$672.00 ','springbreak' => '$762.00 ','late' => '$672.00 ','closing' => '$474.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 7','early' => '$553.00 ','middec' => '$784.00 ','christmas' => '$889.00 ','powder' => '$784.00 ','presidents' => '$889.00 ','spring' => '$784.00 ','springbreak' => '$889.00 ','late' => '$784.00 ','closing' => '$553.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 8','early' => '$632.00 ','middec' => '$896.00 ','christmas' => '$1016.00 ','powder' => '$896.00 ','presidents' => '$1016.00 ','spring' => '$896.00 ','springbreak' => '$1016.00 ','late' => '$896.00 ','closing' => '$632.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 9','early' => '$711.00 ','middec' => '$1008.00 ','christmas' => '$1143.00 ','powder' => '$1008.00 ','presidents' => '$1143.00 ','spring' => '$1008.00 ','springbreak' => '$1143.00 ','late' => '$1008.00 ','closing' => '$711.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 10','early' => '$790.00 ','middec' => '$1120.00 ','christmas' => '$1270.00 ','powder' => '$1120.00 ','presidents' => '$1270.00 ','spring' => '$1120.00 ','springbreak' => '$1270.00 ','late' => '$1120.00 ','closing' => '$790.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 11','early' => '$869.00 ','middec' => '$1232.00 ','christmas' => '$1397.00 ','powder' => '$1232.00 ','presidents' => '$1397.00 ','spring' => '$1232.00 ','springbreak' => '$1397.00 ','late' => '$1232.00 ','closing' => '$869.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 12','early' => '$948.00 ','middec' => '$1344.00 ','christmas' => '$1524.00 ','powder' => '$1344.00 ','presidents' => '$1524.00 ','spring' => '$1344.00 ','springbreak' => '$1524.00 ','late' => '$1344.00 ','closing' => '$948.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 13','early' => '$1027.00 ','middec' => '$1456.00 ','christmas' => '$1651.00 ','powder' => '$1456.00 ','presidents' => '$1651.00 ','spring' => '$1456.00 ','springbreak' => '$1651.00 ','late' => '$1456.00 ','closing' => '$1027.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 14','early' => '$1106.00 ','middec' => '$1568.00 ','christmas' => '$1778.00 ','powder' => '$1568.00 ','presidents' => '$1778.00 ','spring' => '$1568.00 ','springbreak' => '$1778.00 ','late' => '$1568.00 ','closing' => '$1106.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Adult 15','early' => '$1185.00 ','middec' => '$1680.00 ','christmas' => '$1905.00 ','powder' => '$1680.00 ','presidents' => '$1905.00 ','spring' => '$1680.00 ','springbreak' => '$1905.00 ','late' => '$1680.00 ','closing' => '$1185.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 1','early' => 'na','middec' => 'na','christmas' => 'na','powder' => 'na','presidents' => 'na','spring' => 'na','springbreak' => 'na','late' => 'na','closing' => 'na'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 2','early' => 'na','middec' => 'na','christmas' => 'na','powder' => 'na','presidents' => 'na','spring' => 'na','springbreak' => 'na','late' => 'na','closing' => 'na'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 3','early' => 'na','middec' => 'na','christmas' => 'na','powder' => 'na','presidents' => 'na','spring' => 'na','springbreak' => 'na','late' => 'na','closing' => 'na'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 4','early' => 'na','middec' => 'na','christmas' => 'na','powder' => 'na','presidents' => 'na','spring' => 'na','springbreak' => 'na','late' => 'na','closing' => 'na'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 5','early' => '0','middec' => '0','christmas' => '0','powder' => '0','presidents' => '0','spring' => '0','springbreak' => '0','late' => '0','closing' => '0'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 6','early' => '0','middec' => '0','christmas' => '0','powder' => '0','presidents' => '0','spring' => '0','springbreak' => '0','late' => '0','closing' => '0'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 7','early' => '0','middec' => '0','christmas' => '0','powder' => '0','presidents' => '0','spring' => '0','springbreak' => '0','late' => '0','closing' => '0'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 8','early' => '0','middec' => '0','christmas' => '0','powder' => '0','presidents' => '0','spring' => '0','springbreak' => '0','late' => '0','closing' => '0'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 9','early' => '0','middec' => '0','christmas' => '0','powder' => '0','presidents' => '0','spring' => '0','springbreak' => '0','late' => '0','closing' => '0'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 10','early' => '0','middec' => '0','christmas' => '0','powder' => '0','presidents' => '0','spring' => '0','springbreak' => '0','late' => '0','closing' => '0'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 11','early' => '0','middec' => '0','christmas' => '0','powder' => '0','presidents' => '0','spring' => '0','springbreak' => '0','late' => '0','closing' => '0'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 12','early' => '0','middec' => '0','christmas' => '0','powder' => '0','presidents' => '0','spring' => '0','springbreak' => '0','late' => '0','closing' => '0'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 13','early' => '0','middec' => '0','christmas' => '0','powder' => '0','presidents' => '0','spring' => '0','springbreak' => '0','late' => '0','closing' => '0'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 14','early' => '0','middec' => '0','christmas' => '0','powder' => '0','presidents' => '0','spring' => '0','springbreak' => '0','late' => '0','closing' => '0'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Kids Ski Free 15','early' => '0','middec' => '0','christmas' => '0','powder' => '0','presidents' => '0','spring' => '0','springbreak' => '0','late' => '0','closing' => '0'),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 1','early' => '$85.00 ','middec' => '$100.00 ','christmas' => '$115.00 ','powder' => '$100.00 ','presidents' => '$115.00 ','spring' => '$100.00 ','springbreak' => '$115.00 ','late' => '$100.00 ','closing' => '$85.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 2','early' => '$170.00 ','middec' => '$200.00 ','christmas' => '$230.00 ','powder' => '$200.00 ','presidents' => '$230.00 ','spring' => '$200.00 ','springbreak' => '$230.00 ','late' => '$200.00 ','closing' => '$170.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 3','early' => '$255.00 ','middec' => '$300.00 ','christmas' => '$345.00 ','powder' => '$300.00 ','presidents' => '$345.00 ','spring' => '$300.00 ','springbreak' => '$345.00 ','late' => '$300.00 ','closing' => '$255.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 4','early' => '$340.00 ','middec' => '$400.00 ','christmas' => '$460.00 ','powder' => '$400.00 ','presidents' => '$460.00 ','spring' => '$400.00 ','springbreak' => '$460.00 ','late' => '$400.00 ','closing' => '$340.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 5','early' => '$355.00 ','middec' => '$475.00 ','christmas' => '$540.00 ','powder' => '$475.00 ','presidents' => '$540.00 ','spring' => '$475.00 ','springbreak' => '$540.00 ','late' => '$475.00 ','closing' => '$355.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 6','early' => '$426.00 ','middec' => '$570.00 ','christmas' => '$648.00 ','powder' => '$570.00 ','presidents' => '$648.00 ','spring' => '$570.00 ','springbreak' => '$648.00 ','late' => '$570.00 ','closing' => '$426.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 7','early' => '$497.00 ','middec' => '$665.00 ','christmas' => '$756.00 ','powder' => '$665.00 ','presidents' => '$756.00 ','spring' => '$665.00 ','springbreak' => '$756.00 ','late' => '$665.00 ','closing' => '$497.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 8','early' => '$568.00 ','middec' => '$760.00 ','christmas' => '$864.00 ','powder' => '$760.00 ','presidents' => '$864.00 ','spring' => '$760.00 ','springbreak' => '$864.00 ','late' => '$760.00 ','closing' => '$568.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 9','early' => '$639.00 ','middec' => '$855.00 ','christmas' => '$972.00 ','powder' => '$855.00 ','presidents' => '$972.00 ','spring' => '$855.00 ','springbreak' => '$972.00 ','late' => '$855.00 ','closing' => '$639.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 10','early' => '$710.00 ','middec' => '$950.00 ','christmas' => '$1080.00 ','powder' => '$950.00 ','presidents' => '$1080.00 ','spring' => '$950.00 ','springbreak' => '$1080.00 ','late' => '$950.00 ','closing' => '$710.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 11','early' => '$781.00 ','middec' => '$1045.00 ','christmas' => '$1188.00 ','powder' => '$1045.00 ','presidents' => '$1188.00 ','spring' => '$1045.00 ','springbreak' => '$1188.00 ','late' => '$1045.00 ','closing' => '$781.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 12','early' => '$852.00 ','middec' => '$1140.00 ','christmas' => '$1296.00 ','powder' => '$1140.00 ','presidents' => '$1296.00 ','spring' => '$1140.00 ','springbreak' => '$1296.00 ','late' => '$1140.00 ','closing' => '$852.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 13','early' => '$923.00 ','middec' => '$1235.00 ','christmas' => '$1404.00 ','powder' => '$1235.00 ','presidents' => '$1404.00 ','spring' => '$1235.00 ','springbreak' => '$1404.00 ','late' => '$1235.00 ','closing' => '$923.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 14','early' => '$994.00 ','middec' => '$1330.00 ','christmas' => '$1512.00 ','powder' => '$1330.00 ','presidents' => '$1512.00 ','spring' => '$1330.00 ','springbreak' => '$1512.00 ','late' => '$1330.00 ','closing' => '$994.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Teen 15','early' => '$1065.00 ','middec' => '$1425.00 ','christmas' => '$1620.00 ','powder' => '$1425.00 ','presidents' => '$1620.00 ','spring' => '$1425.00 ','springbreak' => '$1620.00 ','late' => '$1425.00 ','closing' => '$1065.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 1','early' => '$55.00 ','middec' => '$70.00 ','christmas' => '$80.00 ','powder' => '$70.00 ','presidents' => '$80.00 ','spring' => '$70.00 ','springbreak' => '$80.00 ','late' => '$70.00 ','closing' => '$55.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 2','early' => '$110.00 ','middec' => '$140.00 ','christmas' => '$160.00 ','powder' => '$140.00 ','presidents' => '$160.00 ','spring' => '$140.00 ','springbreak' => '$160.00 ','late' => '$140.00 ','closing' => '$110.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 3','early' => '$165.00 ','middec' => '$210.00 ','christmas' => '$240.00 ','powder' => '$210.00 ','presidents' => '$240.00 ','spring' => '$210.00 ','springbreak' => '$240.00 ','late' => '$210.00 ','closing' => '$165.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 4','early' => '$220.00 ','middec' => '$280.00 ','christmas' => '$320.00 ','powder' => '$280.00 ','presidents' => '$320.00 ','spring' => '$280.00 ','springbreak' => '$320.00 ','late' => '$280.00 ','closing' => '$220.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 5','early' => '$275.00 ','middec' => '$350.00 ','christmas' => '$400.00 ','powder' => '$350.00 ','presidents' => '$400.00 ','spring' => '$350.00 ','springbreak' => '$400.00 ','late' => '$350.00 ','closing' => '$275.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 6','early' => '$294.00 ','middec' => '$372.00 ','christmas' => '$408.00 ','powder' => '$372.00 ','presidents' => '$408.00 ','spring' => '$372.00 ','springbreak' => '$408.00 ','late' => '$372.00 ','closing' => '$294.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 7','early' => '$343.00 ','middec' => '$434.00 ','christmas' => '$476.00 ','powder' => '$434.00 ','presidents' => '$476.00 ','spring' => '$434.00 ','springbreak' => '$476.00 ','late' => '$434.00 ','closing' => '$343.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 8','early' => '$392.00 ','middec' => '$496.00 ','christmas' => '$544.00 ','powder' => '$496.00 ','presidents' => '$544.00 ','spring' => '$496.00 ','springbreak' => '$544.00 ','late' => '$496.00 ','closing' => '$392.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 9','early' => '$441.00 ','middec' => '$558.00 ','christmas' => '$612.00 ','powder' => '$558.00 ','presidents' => '$612.00 ','spring' => '$558.00 ','springbreak' => '$612.00 ','late' => '$558.00 ','closing' => '$441.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 10','early' => '$490.00 ','middec' => '$620.00 ','christmas' => '$680.00 ','powder' => '$620.00 ','presidents' => '$680.00 ','spring' => '$620.00 ','springbreak' => '$680.00 ','late' => '$620.00 ','closing' => '$490.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 11','early' => '$539.00 ','middec' => '$682.00 ','christmas' => '$748.00 ','powder' => '$682.00 ','presidents' => '$748.00 ','spring' => '$682.00 ','springbreak' => '$748.00 ','late' => '$682.00 ','closing' => '$539.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 12','early' => '$588.00 ','middec' => '$744.00 ','christmas' => '$816.00 ','powder' => '$744.00 ','presidents' => '$816.00 ','spring' => '$744.00 ','springbreak' => '$816.00 ','late' => '$744.00 ','closing' => '$588.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 13','early' => '$637.00 ','middec' => '$806.00 ','christmas' => '$884.00 ','powder' => '$806.00 ','presidents' => '$884.00 ','spring' => '$806.00 ','springbreak' => '$884.00 ','late' => '$806.00 ','closing' => '$637.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 14','early' => '$686.00 ','middec' => '$868.00 ','christmas' => '$952.00 ','powder' => '$868.00 ','presidents' => '$952.00 ','spring' => '$868.00 ','springbreak' => '$952.00 ','late' => '$868.00 ','closing' => '$686.00 '),
  array('tickettype' => 'Child 15','early' => '$735.00 ','middec' => '$930.00 ','christmas' => '$1020.00 ','powder' => '$930.00 ','presidents' => '$1020.00 ','spring' => '$930.00 ','springbreak' => '$1020.00 ','late' => '$930.00 ','closing' => '$735.00 ')
);
```

I need to assign a date range to the columns "early","middec","christmas"...etc.  So when the user selects the date in the date picker it would assign value based on pricing for that time period.  Example: early = 12-01-2016 thru 12-16-2016

Tickettype could be addressed with a radio button or select options (idk which is best), and then the number of days added to the value of ticket type which I have currently set as a select dropdown.

I'm not entirely sure where to start from here.  I got the array from MySQL database, if it is super necessary I guess I could build the table with all the exact dates I just figured you could create an if statement to take the date range and assign it to one of the date columns in the array/table.

Thank You in Advance!  Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to handle user events and then make a ajax request to retreive and populate the price field.